# Зачем нужна куча?

Tags: c#, memory

Понимаю, что стек это временно, пока хранится в области видимости  {}, значимые типы - хранятся в стеке, а переменная содержит адрес её в стеке, ссылочные хранят в стеке ссылку на кучу в которой содержится объект. 
Но почему бы не оставить что либо одно? Да, стек объёмом всего 1мб, но почему его нельзя было расширить? 
 
В чем преимущества такого подхода и зачем стоило создавать такое деление? 
 
Естественно, искал, но ответов малу-по-малу.

Comment: _но почему его нельзя было расширить_ - за счет чего например?

Comment: Стек можно увеличивать/уменьшать (в разумных пределах, конечно же). По крайней мере в линуксе.

Стек - это очень удобно (например, для рекурсий) и производительно (меньше работы уборщику мусора). В Java после того, как научились делать "Escape analyze", и сохранять локальные объекты в стеке, сильно ускорили некоторые случаи выделения мелких объектов.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну он как раз и спрашивает, раз с ним все так быстро, почему только его всегда не использовать? :-)

Comment: Да можно в принципе. Только получиться что то в стиле хаскеля/лиспа. Говоря более по простому - если нужны долгоиграющие объекты, то без стека сложновато.

Comment: @KoVadim, может наоборот без кучи?

Comment: @kovadim, но почему?

Comment: да да, без кучи.

Comment: До этого кто-то говорил, что проще избавиться от кучи, но Рихтер пишет обратное, что с каждым выделением памяти нужно мол время и этого затратно, а в стек захотел - мол, на друг, держи без проблем. И оперирлвание большими объектами в куче легче, чем в стеке. Из-за чего? Указатель проще получить или что? Из моих соображений, стэк строго последовательная величина и перетаскивать постоянно обэектв,а если ещё и тяжёлые - долго и низко производитель но, но не зн чем это доказать, есть тот, кто моэет? Всем спасибо за такую бурную реакцию, честно, не ожидал

Comment: Выделить память в стеке - это просто изменить один регистр (в шарпе  возможно есть ещё чуточку накладок, на то он и управляемый язык). Выделение памяти в куче - это в лучшем случае поиск в заранее выделенной памяти подходящего куска памяти. В худшем случае - это обращение к операционной системе. А это переключение контекста, своппинг и много чего (в зависимости от аппетитов).

Comment: @KoVadim, к куче в шарпе - в большинстве случаев тоже просто сдвинуть указатель. Если сборка мусора не запустится.

Answer (score 20):

Для начала, куча, как и стек — деталь имплементации. Стандарт языка не предписывает использование кучи для хранения объектов.

В Майкрософтовской имплементации C# куча используется потому, что в ней *удобно* размещать долгоживущие объекты.

Каким большим не был бы стек, он работает так, что по окончанию работы функции выделенные на стеке объекты умирают. Поэтому если время жизни объекта превышает (или *потенциально* превышает) время выполнения функции, которая его создала, стек для такого объекта не подходит.

Хуже того, объект можно освободить из стека только после того, как все предыдущие объекты освобождены. Это значит, что в коде

```
string f()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // цикл заполнения
    string s = sb.ToString();
    return s;
}
```

объект `sb`, который создаётся до объекта строки, будет лежать в стеке, и не сможет быть освобождён, пока вызывающей функции нужен объект `s`!

---

Из двух сущностей — кучи и стека — проще избавиться от *стека*, и выделять все объекты в куче. Стандарт языка не предписывает, что стековые объекты *обязаны* умирать вместе с фреймом стека (стандарт языка вовсе не упоминает стек), поэтому если такие объекты съест когда-нибудь потом сборщик мусора, ничего страшного не произойдёт. Но это менее эффективно, чем размещение переменных на стеке, т. к. увеличивает нагрузку на сборщик мусора.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47563/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---).